# linux script counter issue

Tags: linux, counter

The script works fine as it should, it shows the folders contained on a given path, but I am trying to add a counter to know how many there are but it won't work
I've tryed many things, googled etc but can't get it right
What's the problem?
Sorry for the Spanish

the code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6ogf.jpg

it prints this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTvl0.jpg

Comment: Please paste the actual code in your questions rather than screenshots. It's much easier to handle and actually searchable.

Answer (score 1):

You must use "let" in front of your variable reassignment in the loop.

```
let $contador = $contador + 1
```

Comment: works just the same way with the let :/, thanks though

Answer (score 1):

try let but this way

`let contador = $contador + 1`

example:

```
[~]=> c=100; for i in {0..45}; do let c=$c+1; done; echo $c
146
```

On the side note, your whole script looks to do this :

`find . -type d  -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print | wc -l`

any particular reason you don't use `find`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do variable assignment with the dollar symbol on the left side. That is, you should do:

```
var=...
```

Not

```
$var=...
```

And, in addition to using 'let' you can increment your variable like this

```
var=$(( var + 1 ))
```